# cakephp - using loadmodel and getting data related to the loaded model

Tags: php, cakephp

In a controller which is completely unrelated - a DoctorsController, I need to get some info from my ChildrenMedicine model and also the name of the medicine which is in it's own related Medicine model. So in my (unrelated) DoctorsController controller I use:

```
$this->loadModel('ChildrenMedicine');
$this->ChildrenMedicine->recursive = 2;
$childsMeds = $this->ChildrenMedicine->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('child_id'=>$child)));
```

I expected this to get me an array with all the medicines which the child currently uses, plus the info from the medicines table so I can get the name. However it only gives me:

```
$childsMeds[0]['ChildrenMedicine']
$childsMeds[1]['ChildrenMedicine']
```

whereas I was hoping for

```
$childsMeds[0]['ChildrenMedicine']
$childsMeds[0]['Medicine']
$childsMeds[0]['Child']
$childsMeds[1]['ChildrenMedicine']
$childsMeds[1]['Medicine']
$childsMeds[1]['Child']
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

EDIT - my ChildrenMedicine model associations:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Child' => array(
        'className' => 'Child',
        'foreignKey' => 'child_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Medicine' => array(
        'className' => 'Medicine',
        'foreignKey' => 'medicine_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Comment: Can you post your ChildrenMedicine model associations?

Comment: @Sixthpoint I posted it above, thanks for looking :)

Comment: simple checks, you have a foreign key in the ChildrenMedicine table call both "medicine_id" and "child_id". Also, make sure that you have data linking the associations. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto

Comment: I am able to retrieve the info I want if I do $childsMedicines = $this->ChildrenMedicine->findAllByChildId($this->Session->read('Child.id')); in the ChildrenMedicineController so the associations must be ok?!?

Comment: Yes, make sure that both your the Child and Medicine both have the hasone or hasmany relationships set.

Comment: both child and medicine have hasandbelongstomany relationships to each other, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use Containable Behavior.

```
$this->loadModel('ChildrenMedicine');
$this->ChildrenMedicine->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$childsMeds = $this->ChildrenMedicine->find('all', 
                  array(
                      'conditions' => array('child_id'=>$child),
                      'contain' => array('Child', 'Medicine')
                  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

A alternative method would be to use joins to solve this issue. It would be a better option that relying on setting recursive = 2.

```
    $data = $this->ChildrenMedicine->find('all', array('conditions' => array('child_id'=>$child),  'joins' => array(  
            array( 
                'table' => 'medicines', 
                'alias' => 'Medicine', 
                'type' => 'inner', // could also do outter
                'foreignKey' => false, 
                'conditions'=> array('ChildrenMedicine.medicine_id= Medicine.medicine_id')  
            ))));
```

You can read more on [joins here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)

For setting up HABTM relationships [this article](http://rottmann.net/2012/07/cakephp-hasandbelongstomany-relationship-queries-demystified/) seems helpful. Look at "The Model" code

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've just tried this but it returns the exact same result. In otherwords it doesn't have the associated Medicine